# Accessing C drive in Nokia Lumia 620

Tags: cleaning

I have a Nokia Lumia 620 and I had connected it my computer it then showed the phone's C drive with 1.3 GB free. I thought let me delete some unnecessary files. it then shows folders like "Documents", "Pictures", "Videos" etc, when I opened Documents folder I cannot see any files, and it says 0 files, whereas I have some pdfs downloaded through Adobe Acrobat on my phone, but I am not able to access it or move it my computer, Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Do you want help with cleaning out unnecessary files? Or do you specifically want to know about where the PDF's are?

Comment: No I just want to clean up space on my C drive, Any tips for this?

Answer (score 3):

I would think the Documents folder is only for Microsoft Office files that you create locally on your phone (not on Onedrive). Anything that is opened in Adobe on your phone is probably stored in that app's local memory which you cannot access by connecting to your computer.

The easiest solution would be to try and email the PDF from the Adobe app on your phone and get it that way.

Answer (score 2):

What you saw was not equivalent to a computer drive. You cannot access all of the files of the phone from here. What you saw was the shared files of the phone. All apps have their own isolated storage, or can also access this shared area. If it does, it will list that as a capability before you download the app. Most apps such as the PDF reader you mentioned save to their own private storage.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Reader might saved those files in it's own application specific storage. You can move it to PC by uploading to Acrobat.com cloud storage or send via email from Adobe Reader. You can delete those files from Adobe Reader itself by tap and hold file and then delete.

Comment: Yes, finally I had to do it that way. I uploaded the document to files.acrobat.com, then opened my computer and downloaded it from thee. But this over-reliance on an Internet Connection to just transfer files really puzzles and irritates me. Why cant these high end Nokia Lumia phones function like an external Hard Disk or a pen drive? Its like taking a circuitous route to reach your destination. This was never the case with older Symbian phones.