# How to delete a file?

Tags: htc

I have sent a file that is not supported by my phone. Where will I find that file if I want to delete it? eg. I have sent a PDF file but I don't have any PDF readers installed on the phone.

As this phone is a HTC 8x it doesn't have an SD card slot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C drive in Nokia Lumia 620](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/accessing-c-drive-in-nokia-lumia-620)

Comment: The other question pertains to how files are stored when accessing via a computer. This one asks what happens to a file that is transferred that has no file handler. They are different.

Answer (score 1):

If the file opened an app when you transferred, you need to see if the app saved it. Since you mentioned it was a PDF, both Microsoft and adobe PDF apps save the files to their isolated storage. You can go into the app and select the file or files you want and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to PDF Reader (whatever app that you are using) you should see a list of PDF files there, Tap and hold on the file you want to delete. Tap *delete* button.